# $1^{p−1}+2^{p−1}+…+(p−1)^{p−1}≡−1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, formal-proofs

I need help proving the following
Let p be an odd and prime, prove that  $1^{p−1}+2^{p−1}+…+(p−1)^{p−1}≡−1 \pmod p$

Comment: Surprisingly, this is trivial.  By Fermat 's little th.  $a^{p-1 } \equiv 1 \mod p $.  So the sum is $1+1+1+...+1\mod p $.  How many ones? p-1 ones.

Answer (score 6):

Well by Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for all $a$ such that $p \not \mid a$.

Hence:

$$ 1^{p-1}+2^{p-1}+\ldots+(p-1)^{p-1} \equiv 1+1+\ldots+1 = p-1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

Comment: I understand Fermat's little theorem but I still do not see how to arrive at -1 (mod p)

Comment: Every element in the sum becomes $1$, and there are $p-1$ elements in the sum, so the total sum becomes $p-1$, which is congruent to $-1 \pmod{p}$

Answer (score 3):

By Fermat's little theorem, $i^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ for $p$ not dividing $i$. So, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^{p-1}\equiv \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} 1 \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$